# Need help in Gnuplot (fits dont fit

Tags: gnuplot, physics

I'm working on a Gnuplot code for the logarithmic representation of data on fluorescence lifetime development, but the fits are not being displayed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
reset session
cd '...'
set key right bottom invert
set xlabel "Zeit (ns)"
set ylabel "Ticks/max(Ticks)"
set xrange [0:8]
set yrange [0.0001:10]
set logscale y 10
plot "FLIM.dat" using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars title "Daten"

f(x)=a*exp(-x/b)
g(x)=c*exp(-x/d)
h(x)=e*x+f
fit [2:8] f(x)  "FLIM.dat" using 1:(log($2)) via a,b
fit [2:8] g(x)  "FLIM.dat" using 1:(log($2)):($3/$2) via c,d
fit [2:8] h(x)  "FLIM.dat" using 1:(log($2)) via e,f
replot [2:8] f(x) title "fit ohne Fehler" lt rgb "black" 
replot [2:8] g(x) title "fit mit Fehler" lt rgb "red"
replot [2:8] exp(h(x)) title "fit per Gerade" lt rgb "green"`
```

This code produces the following plot:
[image: The plot]

But f(x) and g(x) should be closer to h(x).

I appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide your data if you want people to test your script under "realistic" conditions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you are interested in a solution please provide the data!